# Return Volley Result to a different class

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-volley, return-value

how can I get the result of a StringRequest or JsonObjectRequest back to the class where I called the method.
In my MainActivty I have a Login Button. When I press it, it Calls the function checkLogin with a StingRequest from my Backgroundworker.class. How can I get the response back to my MainActivity to process it or Display it?
I can’t use a return at the end of the method because its asynchrony. I tried calling a method in my MainActivity but I always get an error when reaching the Intent

```
2019-05-16 16:43:52.794 3158-3158/com.test.Test E/Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
```

What’s the proper way to do a login function like this?

-MainActivity

```
package com.test.Test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.test.Test.tools.BackgroundWorker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText txtEditUser;
    private EditText txtEditPw;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnRegister;
    private TextView txtViewLoginfailed;
    private String user;
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtEditUser = findViewById(R.id.txtEditUser);
        txtEditPw = findViewById(R.id.txtEditPw);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        txtViewLoginfailed = findViewById(R.id.txtViewLoginfailed);

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                user = txtEditUser.getText().toString();
                password = txtEditPw.getText().toString();
                new BackgroundWorker().checkLogin(user, password, getApplicationContext());
            }
        });
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent register = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
                startActivity(register);
            }
        });
    }

    public void Login(Boolean LoginOK,Context context) {
        if (LoginOK) {
            Intent menu = new Intent(context, Menu.class);
            startActivity(menu);
        } else {
            txtViewLoginfailed.setText("Login failed");
        }
    }
}
```

-Backgroundworker

```
public class BackgroundWorker {
    private Boolean LoginOK;

    public void checkLogin(final String user, final String password, final Context context) {

        String url = "http://192.168.0.2:80/webapp/login.php";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("testLogin", "3");
                            if (response.equals("login success")) {
                                LoginOK = true;
                                new MainActivity().Login(LoginOK, context);
                            } else {
                                Log.d("testLogin", "5");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Error", exc.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_name", user);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Callback` interface.

Create new interface e.g. `LoginRequestCallback`:

```java
public interface LoginRequestCallback {
    void onLoginRequestSuccess();
    void onLoginRequestError(String errorMessage);
}
```

In your `checkLogin` method add new parameter `LoginRequestCallback callback`:

```java
    public void checkLogin(final String user, final String password, final Context context, LoginRequestCallback callback) { ... }
```

And then call method corresponding to either success of login or to the error:

```java
public void checkLogin(final String user, final String password, final Context context) {

        String url = "http://192.168.0.2:80/webapp/login.php";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d("testLogin", "3");
                            if (response.equals("login success")) {                           
                                callback.onLoginRequestSuccess();
                            } else {
                                callback.onLoginRequestError("Invalid credentials");
                            }
                        } catch (Exception exc) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e("Error", exc.getMessage());
                            callback.onLoginRequestError(exc.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
                        callback.onLoginRequestError(exc.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_name", user);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }
```

When calling from `MainActivity`, make `MainActivity` class implement this interface:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoginRequestCallback { 
//... 

    @Override
    public void onLoginRequestSuccess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoginRequestError(String errorMessage) {

    }

}
```

And when you call this method, pass `this` as callback:

```java
void onLoginButtonClicked(View v) {
    String user = "Asd";
    String password = "asdasd";
    this.backgroundWorker.checkLogin(user, password, this, this);
}

@Override
public void onLoginRequestSuccess() {
    this.Login(true, this);
}

@Override
public void onLoginRequestError(String errorMessage) {
    Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have two Problems with your last Code block.
How do I pass "this" as a callback?
I tried: new MainActivity().onLoginButtonClicked(this);
The error massage for this is:
onLoginButtonClicked (android.view.View)in MainActivity cannot be applied to (anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener)
And the last part of the method onLoginButtonClicked doesn’t work
        this.BackgroundWorker.checkLogin(user, password, this, this);
 Error Massage: Cannot resolve symbol 'BackgroundWorker'
Can I Use instead:
new BackgroundWorker().checkLogin(user, password, this, this);